# Is it possible to save an intent object with onSaveInstanceState?

Tags: java, android

I need to return some data when I return from my activity B to my activity A:

In Acivity B:

```
    Intent intentSendData;

    private void saveData(){
        intentSendData = new Intent(AcivityB.this, AcivityA.class);
        //Here I put the data to the intention
        result = true;
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intentSendData);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean("result", result);
        outState.putParcelable("intentSendData", intentSendData);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        result = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("result");
        if (result) {
            setResult(RESULT_OK);
            intentSendData = (Intent) savedInstanceState.getParcelable("intentSendData");
        }
    }
```

`saveData()` works fine to return information to my activity A, But if I rotate the screen before returning to Activity A the information is lost because intentSendData becomes null, I tried to use `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` but I can't get it to work, what should I do to avoid losing the information when rotating the screen?

Comment: Who is A and who is B? And in which one did you try to use onSaveInstanceState? All is pretty unclear as we dont see what you do with that intent.

Comment: As indicated above, all that code belongs to activity B. I just need intentSendData not to become null when rotating the screen to use its information when returning to my Activity A, I did not attach code from Activity A because I know how to control that in `onActivityResult`.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

Comment: `the information is lost because intentSendData becomes null,` Which information? And what does it matter? You are creating a new intent with `intentSendData = new Intent(AcivityB.this, AcivityA.class);`. So it is not null. You are not showing where you call saveData(). And where is the finish(); ? When do you end activity B and where is that code? Please do. Also we cannot see an onActivityResult() of activity A where you should receive the result.

Comment: You code does not make sense - the point of `setResult` is to return a result to another Activity, This assumes that the current activity will be finishing, Given that, there is no need to save any information across orientation change.

Comment: I really appreciate everyone's help, an apology for the lack of details, I have fixed the problem I added an answer with the explanation

Comment: You can't save the intent, but you can save the intent.extras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > //Here I put the data to the intention

Instead you should save all that data in `onSaveInstanceState()`.

You cannot save an intent there.

Only create an intent and put the data in it when you are done with B.

Comment: I was just considering doing this until I saw my mistake, now that I know both options work I would like some advice, what is the best practice?

Comment: I have no idea about which other option you are talking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this problem by overriding `onConfigurationChanged()` .
You want to save the data because the activity executes the `oncreate()` method when the screen is rotated.
So if the data is not lost when the screen is rotated, there is no need to save the data.
Add `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"` to your activity in AndroidManifest, then override `onConfigurationChanged()`

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        // do nothing or do something you want when the screen is rotated
    } else if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        // do nothing or do something you want when the screen is rotated
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All I needed was to get some sleep, the mistake is in `onRestoreInstanceState` the problem was that I was not passing the intention to `setResult()`. Then i changed `setResult(RESULT_OK);` to `setResult(RESULT_OK, intentSendData);` and now it works correctly.

Comment: Are you telling here that it is possible to save an intent with onSaveInstanceState() ? Hmmm.. if this is your second option then i advice you to use the first one. ;-).

Comment: I did not think it was possible either but it is.... You are right I will use your approach thank you very much